# Use of DMSString[]

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I am attempting to translate some latitude/longitude data from a Central American museum collection.  My questions relate to the proper use of the DMSString[] function.

Upon importing, I have a list of 252 entries providing latitude/longitude.  However, these data are discovered to be in multiple formats that I wish to convert to a single DMSString format.  For purposes of this question a small
test set is sufficient and given below, using only latitude data, since presumably longitude data would be treated identically:

```
 latitudetest = {"", "9,53333377838135", "8,02499961853027",  "9,72166633605957", "9,60333347320557", "8,58166694641113",   "10,3333330154419", "10,4177780151367", "10,4166669845581", "",   "9,55666637420654", "9,56999969482422", "8,78333377838135", "9,569167137146", "9,55833339691162", "09º47.88N", ""}
```

Note that 3 distinct types of the data are present:

latitudetest[[1]] is Null, 
latitudetest[[2]] contains a number expressed as a string, observing that, as in many Latin American countries, a comma is used rather than a decimal point.
latitudetest[[16]] is in a distinct format with an unusual symbol given rather than the typical degree symbol.

To address these 3 types I have written a function:

```
latitudefix[x_] := Module[{y}, y = StringReplace[x, {"," -> "."}]];
```

which, when mapped onto the list addresses the use of a comma rather than a decimal point

```
 latitudetest1 = Map[latitudefix, latitudetest]
```

Similary, I address the problem of the unusual symbol by replacing it with a degree symbol:

```
 latitudefix2[x_ ] := Module[{y}, y = StringReplace[x, {"º" -> "\[Degree]"}]]

 latitudetest2 = Map[ latitudefix2, latitudetest1]
```

I note that if I then select a particular part (say latitudetest2[[2]]), I get using

```
 Head[latitudetest2[[2]]
```

a String, indicating that indeed all elements in my list are strings.

However, when I go to Map the DMSString function on to my new list, latitudetest2, I generate errors:

```
 latitudefix3[x_] := Module[{y}, y = DMSString[x, "NS"] // InputForm]

 latitudetest3 = Map[latitudefix3, latitudetest2]
```

DMSString::str:  cannot be interpreted as a degree-minute-second string specification.

DMSString::str: 9.53333377838135 cannot be interpreted as a degree-minute-second string specification.

DMSString::str: 8.02499961853027 cannot be interpreted as a degree-minute-second string specification.

I don't understand why my function doesn't work in the 2nd case, since simply putting in the same string

```
DMSString[9.53333377838135, "NS"]
```

works as expected.

Likewise, I don't know how to use (overload?) the DMSString function to handle the first case where I have a null value (that I simply wish to output back as Null [no character]) or the third, where there the latitude is expressed as partially in DMSStringFormat (ie the degrees are given as a expected, but decimal minutes are not converted into minutes and seconds).

How does one modify these modules so that all three types of input are properly converted to a single "standard" degree, minutes, seconds, hemisphere string, whenever they are encountered in the list of (edited) latitude data?

Comment: Some advice for the importing stage of your problem: look up the option `"NumberPoint"`, which can make things much easier: `ImportString["10,4166669845581", "List", "NumberPoint" -> ","]`.

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't aware of NumberPoint.  It does work nicely if all the values are of type 2 above.  However, it generates a "Missing" when evaluating type 1 above and a failure when dealing with entries are of type 3 above.

Comment: That's... odd, regarding the behavior for your "type 3". Did you put `"NumberPoint" -> ","` in the `Import[]` you were using? Nevertheless, for your "type 1", `Missing[]` is indeed the canonical representation; you can do the replacement `expr /. Missing[__] -> Null` if need be.

Comment: Following the example for InputString in the documentation, I used intnum = Interpreter["Number", NumberPoint -> ","][
  ToExpression[latitude]]

Comment: For the "type 3" there is no ",".  Someone just entered the data already in a partially complete DMSString (ie degrees OK, but minutes as decimal minutes rather than minutes and seconds).

Comment: You said you were importing them, presumably from a file, so I had thought you'd put it in `Import[]`. I tend to avoid `Interpreter[]` because it's a bit finicky.

Comment: Oops.  I that back sometimes the "," is present sometimes its absent.  It's present in the small test piece, but not the column in the imported spreadsheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68254/discussion-between-stuart-poss-and-j-m).